# Is it possible to have apsx pages with VB.Net code behind pages in MVC4 project written in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

We are developing a MVC4 application using C#.Net 4.0, we need to include some pages developed using vb asp.net to our project.

Is it possible to include these aspx pages with vb.net codebehind files to out mvc4 c#.net application ?

My belief is that it is not possible..but still wondering some one can surprise me ..

Comment: no in c# application you cannot include vb pages

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla  but we can mix vb.net code and c#.net code in a website application.I have done that before in traditional asp.net project.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the vb.net project and add the compiled assembly and the aspx pages to your C# project?

Comment: I didn't try it .. but my feeling is that it is possible.